# Showing histograms by percentage with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data that I want to display with a histogram by group (Cohort). Each individual has a Depression score of 1-4. The problem is that there are so many more people in the Fall cohort (it is more exaggerated in the actual data) and therefore I want to show the % by group, that is, the 4 bars for Fall should all add up to 1 (or 100%).

Here is what I've tried. I'm not quite sure the y = stat(density) is doing what I want:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = Depression, fill = Cohort)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(density)),
                 position = "dodge", binwidth = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Here is some data:

```
structure(list(Cohort = c("Fall", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall", 
"Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Spring", 
"Summer", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall", 
"Fall", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall", "Summer", "Fall", 
"Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Spring", 
"Summer", "Spring", "Spring", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall", 
"Fall", "Fall"), Depression = c(1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 
2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 
2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -43L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You want a barplot, not an histogram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a histogram, but I would recommend showing the data like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

test_data %>%
  count(Cohort, Depression) %>%
  group_by(Cohort) %>%
  mutate(percent = n/sum(n)*100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Cohort, percent, fill = as.factor(Depression)))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

You can dodge the position if you don't want them stacked or use "Depression" as the x instead of Cohort. I just wanted to illustrate that they added to 100%.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating. Try

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(d, aes(x = Depression, fill = Cohort)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal()
```

The aesthetic `y = ..density..` comes from the variables computed by `geom_histogram`, see section **Computed variables** in `help("geom_histogram")`. All computed variables must be placed between two dots when used.

An alternative is to use `geom_bar` with `position_fill()`.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = Cohort, fill = factor(Depression))) +
  geom_bar(position = position_fill()) +
  theme_minimal()
```